# "Simple File Sharing" turning off seamlessly

Tags: windows-xp, file-sharing

"Simple File Sharing" needs to be turned off on this WinXP Pro machine. But it needs to be seamless, so that clients connected to it do not encounter errors/disconnects or permission issues.

The machine has a number of drives that are shared to a workgroup.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple file sharing is purely a UI interface.  The logic behind it is the same permissions that the advanced dialog uses (ACLs and Share permissions).

You can turn off simple file sharing under Explorer Tool Menu/Folder Options/Simple File sharing.

Comment: I don't have to explicitly set permissions on existing shares after turning off "Simple file sharing" then?

Comment: No, the current shares keep their permissions.